# Norm of eigen vector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ of order n with distinct eigenvalues, can we bound the norm of the eigenvector matrix ($B=[v_1|\dots|v_n]: v_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the i-th eigen value of $A$) of $A$ using the norm of $A$ (or the coefficient of $A$)?

Comment: 1: There might not be $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. 2: Each eigenvalue has many corresponding eigenvectors. Which one do you pick?

Comment: The matrix B is full rank (Ps: I forgot to add that). Anyone you can choose from the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the eigenvectors, i.e., if $v$ is an eigenvector then $\lambda v$ is as well for all real $\lambda \ne 0$. Thus, you can scale $\|B\|$ as you wish.
PS: $B$ is similar to the diagonalization of $A$, i.e. $B^{-1} A B=D$, a diagonal matrix.